# function as input to another function effect of the where keyword

Tags: julia

I would like to understand what is happening in this example:

In this implementation:

```
using LinearAlgebra
using StaticArrays, BenchmarkTools

function foo(u,p)
    a,b,c,d = p;
    x,y = u;
    return SA_F64[a*x - b*x*y, -c*y + d*x*y];
end

function bar(f, u, h, p) 
    return SVector{2,Float64}(u + h*f(u,p));
end

function baz(f, u, func, p)
    n_p = 100000;
    h = 1.0/n_p;
    out = zeros(n_p, 2);
    for i in 1:n_p
        u = func(f, u, h, p);
        out[i,:]=u
    end
    return out;
end


u = SA_F64[1., 2.];
p = SA_F64[1.5, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0];

@btime baz(foo, u, bar, p)
```

I am getting an execution time of `6.033 ms (399492 allocations: 12.20 MiB)`. This is taking too much memory to compute.

I found an implementation doing:

```
function baz(f::T, u, func, p) where T
    n_p = 100000;
    h = 1.0/n_p;
    out = zeros(n_p, 2);
    for i in 1:n_p
        u = func(f, u, h, p);
        out[i,:]=u
    end
    return out;
end
```

The end result is exactly the same but the computation time is: `1.000 ms (2 allocations: 1.53 MiB)`. Which is incredible!

What is the specification `baz(f::T, u, func, p) where T` doing to get this performance improvement?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the Julia performance tip titled "[Be aware of when Julia avoids specializing](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Be-aware-of-when-Julia-avoids-specializing):

> As a heuristic, Julia avoids automatically specializing on argument type parameters in three specific cases: `Type`, `Function`, and `Vararg`. Julia will always specialize when the argument is used within the method, but not if the argument is just passed through to another function.

Fundamentally, Julia's performance benefits come from inferring types and specializing the code based on that: when we call `sum(50:5:500000)`, Julia infers that the argument is a `StepRange`, and the particular `sum` code that's specific to range arguments is compiled and run. This results in very fast machine code that's specialized to this type.

However, as mentioned above, this specialization doesn't happen for `Function` arguments if they're not directly used (i.e. called) within the code - which is the case here, as `f` is passed to `baz`, but not used there and instead passed on to `bar`. Because of this, Julia sees `f` as only some `Function`, and not as the specific `foo` function until runtime. The page linked above goes on to say:

> This usually has no performance impact at runtime and improves compiler performance. If you find it does have a performance impact at runtime in your case, you can trigger specialization by adding a type parameter to the method declaration.

So adding the type parameter `T` is a signal to the compiler to say "do specialize on the specific function here, and not treat it as a generic `Function`".